# Python Selenium - Iframe Dynamically Change Id and Name But Src is Same

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

Issue : - Unable to detect the iframe and switch to iframe as the iframe id and name dynamically changes at each time it loads but the src remain the same.

Unable to identify the xpath as well. Found iframe tag using `driver.find_element_by_tagname("iframe")` but cant view the tag `<iframe>` in the HTML of the page source. Therefore unable to find the xpath by right click and iframe tag.

Already tried to find the number of frame size using 'frame.size' but since its not callable, it provide answer in dict which is 'height:0,weight:0'

Require to switch to this iframe and work with the element inside the iframe which is to

1) enter  text field into the iframe

2) select radio button in the iframe

Unable to select element after switch to iframe

Screenshot of the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y25nJ.png)

Comment: @NarendraR - do you have solution for this ?

Comment: sometimes the iframe loads when we mouse over on it. then it will be available on page source. You can try that.

Comment: @murthi can you give me a sample on this?

Comment: @Hema, Can you add that iframe HTML code. Or it is possible to share the URL ?

Comment: @Hema you can check my answer

Comment: @ narendrar - I can't share the html code for its security reason. But it basically not detecting the element in the iframe upon switch to the iframe. I was able to confirm the frame source code by comparing the frame source code from the Web with the frame source code upon switching to the new frame using frame.pagesource and it shows the same. Now I'm not sure why it's not locating the element

Comment: @murthi - already checked the answer as below

Comment: I wonder if its anything related to the chromedriver version which prevents this to happen --   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: when i view the page source of the iframe, i'm able to find the element. Its also available when i inspect the element from main page. i'm not sure why its not reading the element after it switch to the iframe

Comment: I've include screenshot of the code. I need to grab the element of "X78"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer this, by determining the number of iframe. I've used 'find_element's'_by_tagname('iframe') instead of find_element_bytagname('iframe') which was able to find more than 1 iframe if exist in the page source.

This provides me total 3 iframe tag. Then i proceed to loop into the iframe and find the attribute of the each iframe such as id,name and src.

Then i noticed one of the iframe src, refers to the web address that has the element which i was looking for. Then i proceed to switch to that particular frame using if statement.

Once switch to the iframe, i proceed to get the element.

This solved on how to switch between frame using python-selenium and detect element upon switch the frame.

The key here is to detect on which frame does the element exist within and able to switch to that frame. The frame could be either nested within one frame or list of frame in the main window.

Upon detect and switch the frame. Then would be able to locate the element. 
This solves the challenges

Answer (score 0):

By default, each frame is assigned an integer number. So you can always do:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. However i manage to get the iframe id using tagname. As there is only 1 <iframe> tag, i lookup for its attribute using '.get_attribute("id) which provide me the id of the dynamic iframe whenever it reload again. Now im not sure if it has done the switch as i'm not able to detect any of the element inside the iframe. The iframe does not give error to '.switch_to.frame(frame.get_attribute('id') code. But when i want to use 'driver.find_element_by_...() it says unable to detect the element. So now i'm not sure why its not getting the element in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until frame to be loaded as given below.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe')))
```

Comment: I tried this already and it give no error but it's not selecting any element inside the iframe. It give error saying 'unable to locate element'. I also tried to load the page source after switching to frame to check if the html content is the same with the actual Web page frame source and it shows same. Now I'm not sure why it's not selecting the element in the iframe and give errors

Comment: have you checked the nested frames? please post your html for the page.

Comment: There's a nested frame but the element is inside the frame1 and not the nested frame(frame2). The Frame2 is target to blank black page.